# Can I use a PyTorch or Tensorflow project on a machine without GPU?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm a noob when it comes to Python and machine learning. I'm trying to run two different projects that have to do with something called Deep Image Matting:

- https://github.com/Joker316701882/Deep-Image-Matting with Tensorflow
- https://github.com/huochaitiantang/pytorch-deep-image-matting with Pytorch

I'm just trying to run the tests in these projects but I run into various problems. Can I run these on a machine without GPU? I thought that GPU is only for speeding up processing, but I'm only interested in seeing these run before getting a machine with GPU.
I apologize in advance, as I know I'm a total noob in this

When I try the Tensorflow project:

1. I get an error with this line `gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = args.gpu_fraction)` probably because I was tf2 and this requires tf1
2. After I downgraded to tf1 when I try to run the test I get `W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.`
    and `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'MaxPoolWithArgmax' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
   <no registered kernels>` and now I'm stuck because I have no clue what this means

When I try the Pytorch project:

1. First I get this error: `RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.`
2. So I added `map_location=torch.device('cpu')` when the model is loaded, but now I get `RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for VGG16:
       size mismatch for conv6_1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([512, 512, 1, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([512, 512, 3, 3]).` And I'm stuck again

Can someone help?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the PyTorch one, there were two problems and it looks like you've solved the first one on your own with map_location. The second problem is that the weights in your checkpoint and the weights in your model don't have the same shape! A quick detour to the github repo; let's visit [net.py](https://github.com/huochaitiantang/pytorch-deep-image-matting/blob/master/core/net.py) in core. Take a look at lines 26 to 28:

```
# model released before 2019.09.09 should use kernel_size=1 & padding=0
# self.conv6_1 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=1, padding=0,bias=True)
self.conv6_1 = nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1,bias=True)
```

I'm guessing the checkpoint is loading weights where conv6_1 has a kernel size of 1 rather than 3, like the commented out line of code. So try uncommenting the line with kernel_size=1 and comment out the line with kernel_size=3.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I did get a bit forward with this, but now I get `AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled`

Comment: Did you call deploy.py with --cuda False?

Comment: If you did, and the error's still showing, then that means somewhere in the code they're manually calling something.cuda() without any if else check, which is throwing the error. It is basically a very poorly written piece of pytorch code. A general good practice is to set some variable device = torch.device('cpu') or torch.device('cuda') and then use something.to(device) throughout the code, instead of manually calling if args.cuda: something.cuda() like the writer of the code did.

Comment: it seems that deploy.sh makes use of some folder `TEST_DATA_ROOT=/home/liuliang/DISK_2T/datasets/matting/Combined_Dataset/Test_set/comp` :-) so it means that I probably have to get a hold of the training data set and then try to run this